# Postgresql accent insensitive for non-accent and sensitive for accent word

Tags: postgresql, accent-insensitive

In Postgresql how to achieve separate search result with and without accent using like/ilike, something like this:

- The record names are: cafe, café, cafeteria
- If I use `select name from cafe-table where name like '%cafe%';` then the result will be `cafe, café, cafeteria`
- But If I select with `%café%` (with the accent) I just want the result is `café`

I've already tried `unaccent` but it makes the result the same for 2 queries.

Comment: `... where (name ilike '%mask%') or (unaccent('mask') = 'mask' and unaccent(name) ilike '%mask%')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) module:

Install:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

Then your query could look like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM cafe-table 
WHERE unaccent(name) like '%cafe%'; -- use unaccent here
```